# Error in Pipe Used to Capitalize Words in a String

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe, angular-pipe

I am trying to create a more robust capitalize pipe in my Angular app. Initially the capitalize pipe I had was only needed to capitalize single words. Now I have a situation where there can be multiple words. This is what my pipe now looks like to handle this kind of scenario:

```
transform(input: any) {
      if (input !== null) {
        const stringArr = input.split(' ');
        let result = ' ';
        const cap = stringArr.length;
        for (let x = 0; x < cap; x++) {
            stringArr[x].toLowerCase();
            if (x === cap - 1) {
            result += stringArr[x].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArr[x].substring(1);
            } else {
            result += stringArr[x].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArr[x].substring(1) + ' ';
            }
      }
    return result;
  }
}
```

But I am getting this error in the console:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: input.split is not a function

Any ideas as to what's off here?

Comment: `if (!input != null)` you have a double negative here, hence split will end up only running on when `input` is `null`

Comment: Good catch, changed that (as you can see above) - still getting the same error though.

Comment: As a side note, I suggest using `Array.prototype.join()` to recompose the full string, that way you would avoid the inner `if` and its code duplication. `input.split(' ').map(word -> word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)).join(' ')` should work nicely.

Comment: `(input || '').split(' ')` Another one. Try it.

Comment: ERROR: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: (input || "").split is not a function

Comment: It'd be interesting to know the `typeof input`, especially now that you've changed your `input` to `any`

Comment: `if (input !== null && typeof input == 'string') {` Try it.

Comment: @Kind user - thanks, this got rid of the error. And it's working for single words, but not for multiple words. Need to look into this some more.

Comment: The reason it's not working with multiple words, is because that field is actually within an array in the db. Will have to think through how to handle that.

Comment: If it's an array, just use `input.toString().split(' ')` or `input.join().split(' ')`.

Comment: There are times when the capitalize pipe will be working on strings, and others it'll be working on an array. Therefore I probably need to add more conditional logic based on type.

Comment: `if (input !== null && typeof input == 'string') { input.split(' ') } else { input.join().split(' ') }`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks @Kind user!

Comment: @Muirik Are you still there? I just wonder if I could make a full answer, for the sake of future readers, who may have the same problem. Do you agree?

Comment: Sure. Sounds good, @Kind user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`String#split`** function is usable only on strings, else you will receive an `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: input.split is not a function` error.

You have to set a condition, that the given element must be a `string`, if not - it has to be changed (if it's possible) into a `string` or just ignored.

```
if (input !== null && typeof input == 'string') { 
  input.split(' ') 
} else { 
  input.join().split(' ') 
}
```